# Problems Sorting Data out of a text-file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a csv file imported into a dataframe and have trouble sorting the data.

df looks like this:

```
    Data
0                          <WindSpeed>0.69</WindSpeed>
1                         <PowerOutput>0</PowerOutput>
2              <ThrustCoEfficient>0</ThrustCoEffici...
3                        <RotorSpeed>8.17</RotorSpeed>
4                     <ReactivePower>0</ReactivePower>
5                                         </DataPoint>
6                                          <DataPoint>
7                          <WindSpeed>0.87</WindSpeed>
8                         <PowerOutput>0</PowerOutput
```

I want it to look like this:

```
0   Windspeed   Poweroutput
1   0.69        0.0
```

Here´s the code that I wrote so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import re
import numpy as np


df= pd.read_csv('powercurve.csv', encoding='utf-8',skiprows=42)
df.columns=['Data']


no_of_rows=df.Data.str.count("WindSpeed").sum()/2
rows=no_of_rows.astype(np.uint32)
TRBX=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,abs(rows)),columns=['WSpd[m/s]','Power[kW]'],dtype='float')
i=0
for i in range(len(df)):

  if 'WindSpeed' in df['Data']:
       TRBX['WSpd[m/s]', i]= re.findall ("'(\d+)'",'Data')


  elif 'Rotorspeed' in df['Data']:
       TRBX['WSpd[m/s]', i]= re.findall ("'(\d+)'",'Data')
```

Is this a suitable approach? If yes, so far there are no values written into the TRBX dataframe. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where is the value `0.24` coming from in your expected output?

Comment: Just a random number, I just wanted to illustrate the format in which i want it to be finally.

Comment: Btw, did you check if your data is not an `XML` file?

Comment: yes, i did. it is not an xml-file.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should help you if your df is indeed in the same format as you:

```
import re

split_func = lambda x: re.split('<|>', str(x))

split_series = df.Data.apply(split_func)
data = a.apply(lambda x: x[2]).rename('data')
features = a.apply(lambda x: x[1]).rename('features')
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(features).T
```

You may want to drop some columns that have no data or input some N/A values afterwards. You also may want to rename the variables and series to different names that make more sense to you.